# Uploading a large file in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I am trying to upload a file in ASP.net MVC and want to give a user a message that "You have exceeded maximum file size" if user exceeds the maximum file size but when I try to upload a large file it gives me Httpstatus code as 200 when i checked IIS logs there are 2 request logged in IIS one is HttpStatusCode 302 and another as 200.I am not doing any kind of redirect but IIS logs are giving me 302.How can I generate 404.13 error for these kind of request and how can I track this error so that I can give a meaningful message.

Comment: Limit the file size on the client. Why would you want to get all the way to the server waste server resources just to tell the user he did something wrong?

Comment: I can't check the file size on the client because for this I need to create a file system object and do the file size and exposing file system is I think a security hack and I am working for an online banking application

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTML5 File API,

```
var size = document.getElementById('myFile').files[0].size;
```

Comment: I need to support IE7 Browser onward

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin [Blueimp jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html)

u can see the plugin configuration [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options).it has an option of setting the max file size so that u can alert the user before a server round-trip.